# Using a WITH as an aggregate value

Tags: sql, presto

I am querying a Presto table where I want to calculate what percentage of the total a certain subset of the rows account for.

Consider a table like this:

| id | m |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 8 |

I want to query to report how much of the total measure (m) is contributed by each id.  In this example, the total of the measure column is 29 can I find it with a query like...

```sql
SELECT SUM("m") FROM t;
```

output:

```
sqlite> SELECT SUM("m") FROM t;
29
```

Then I want to subtotal by id for some of the ids like

```sql
SELECT "id", SUM("m") AS "sub_total" FROM t WHERE "id" IN ('1','3') GROUP BY id;
```

output:

```
sqlite> SELECT "id", SUM("m") AS "sub_total" FROM t WHERE "id" IN ('1','3') GROUP BY id;
1|12
3|8
```

Now I want to add a third column where the subtotals are divided by the grand total (29) to get the percentage for each selected id.

I tried:

```sql
sqlite>
WITH a AS (
 SELECT SUM("m") AS g FROM t )
SELECT "id", SUM("m") AS "sub_total", SUM(m)*100/"a"."g"
FROM a, t
  WHERE "t"."id" IN ('1','3') GROUP BY "t"."id";
```

output:

```
1|12|41
3|8|27
```

Which is all good in SQLLite3!  But when I translate this to my actual Presto DB (and the right tables and columns), I get this error:

```
presto error: line 10:5: 'a.g' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
```

I can't understand what I'm missing here or why this would be different in Presto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `GROUP BY` in your query, all expressions that the query is returning must be either:

- the expression you are grouping by
- or aggregate function

For example if you do `GROUP BY id`, the resulting query will return one row per `id` - you cannot just use `m`, because with `id = 1` there are two values: `5` and `7` - so what should be returned? First value, last, sum, average? You need to tell it using aggregate function like `sum(m)`.

Same with `a.g` - you need to add it to `GROUP BY`.

```
WITH a AS (
 SELECT SUM("m") AS g FROM t )
SELECT "id", SUM("m") AS "sub_total", SUM(m)*100/"a"."g"
FROM a, t
  WHERE "t"."id" IN ('1','3') GROUP BY "t"."id", "a"."g";
```

There's nothing special about PrestoDB here, it's more SQLite that's less strict, actually most other database engines would complain about your case.

Comment: that solved it.  thank you for the debug and the explanation